# Getting "Error Authenticator must be set" when call AuthorizationV1 to obtain speech-to-text token

Tags: ibm-watson

Running Node v10
ibm-watson v5.1.0

Getting error when try to obtain token for speech-to-text.

## #

{
        "message": "Authenticator must be set.",
        "name": "Error",
        "stack": "Error: Authenticator must be set.\n    at AuthorizationV1.BaseService (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/base-service.js:66:19)\n    at new AuthorizationV1 (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/node_modules/ibm-watson/authorization/v1.js:44:28)\n    at Object.token (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/services/stt.js:17:32)\n    at speech-to-text_token (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/index.js:42:54)\n    at Object.exec (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/index.js:33:73)\n    at Promise (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/index.js:10:16)\n    at new Promise ()\n    at NodeActionRunner.main [as userScriptMain] (/nodejsAction/VuncPM95/index.js:9:12)\n    at Promise (/nodejsAction/runner.js:73:35)\n    at new Promise ()"
}

## #

When try with
typescript 3.6.4

## #

{
  "message": "Authenticator must be set.",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Authenticator must be set.\n    at t.e (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :22:45665)\n    at new t (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :16:49145)\n    at Object.token (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :22:44594)\n    at speech-to-text_token (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :22:43617)\n    at Object.exec (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :22:43498)\n    at Promise (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :22:43038)\n    at new Promise ()\n    at NodeActionRunner.a [as userScriptMain] (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:57:23), :22:43016)\n    at Promise (/nodejsAction/runner.js:73:35)\n    at new Promise ()"
}

## #

```
export const SpeechToText = {
  token: (params: WatsonParams) => {
    const sttCredentials = Object.assign(
      {
        username: params.speechToTextUsername, // or hard-code credentials here
        password: params.speechToTextPassword,
        iam_apikey: params.speechToTextIamApikey, // if using an RC service
        url: params.speechToTextUrl ? params.speechToTextUrl : SpeechToTextV1.URL
      },
      vcapServices.getCredentials('speech_to_text') // pulls credentials from environment in bluemix, otherwise returns {}
    );
    const sttAuthService = new AuthorizationV1(sttCredentials);
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      sttAuthService.getToken(function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error retrieving token: ', err);
          observer.error('Error retrieving token...');
        } else {
          const token = response.token || response;
          if (params.speechToTextIamApikey) {
            observer.next({ accessToken: token, url: sttCredentials.url });
          } else {
            observer.next({ token: token, url: sttCredentials.url });
          }
          observer.complete();
        }
      });  
    });
  }  
}
```

Expect it to return a token.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication changed in v5. See [MIGRATION-V5](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V5.md#authentication-mechanism-redesigned---read-this)

> The SDK service constructors now accept `Authenticator` objects that are used to authenticate requests. The constructors no longer accept individual credentials like `username` and `password`.

Here's an example from the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=node#authentication).

```
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: '{apikey}',
  }),
  url: '{url}',
});
```